# Can Kiba support "Bulk" destination instead of 1 by 1?

Tags: ruby, kiba-etl

I understand Kiba's core is to process rows 1 by 1. And I want this, until the destination step.
I want to push the transformed data to a Kafka Topic, however it's preferred to do it in Bulk rather than individually. Is this possible?

Assumming we have the next class

```rb
class TransactionProducer
  def intialize(data: [])
    @data = data
  end

  def push_to_kafka
    $kafka.push(data)
  end
end
```

I `think` this is possible using `post_process` and storing the transformed data in an array.

```rb
data = []

job = Kiba.parse do
  source MySource, source_config

  transform do |row|
    row = Transform...
    data << row
  end

  post_process do
    TransactionProducer.new(data).push_to_kafka
  end
end
```

But im wondering if there's another way?

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to use a `post_process` for this, I would instead recommend to leverage the fact that destinations can implement a `close` method (see https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki/Implementing-ETL-destinations), and use that to "buffer out" to your target (a bit like shown for the aggregating transform here https://thibautbarrere.com/2020/03/05/new-in-kiba-etl-v3).

If you have a large number of rows, you can also use both `write` and `close` to flush out your buffer as soon as you reach a given number of rows (but make sure to flush everything that is remaining in your `close` call).

Comment: @JorgeG great! Could you mark the answer as "solution"? Thanks!